# Cannot download nltk corpus on AWS EMR, I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nltk, amazon-emr

After opening my EMR cluster with JupyterLab. I'm unable to download additional corpus with `nltk.download()`.

**Code**

```
nltk.download('wordnet')
```

**Error**

```
I/O operation on closed file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 817, in download
    show('Downloading collection %r' % msg.collection.id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 783, in show
    subsequent_indent=prefix + prefix2 + ' ' * 4,
  File "/tmp/4461650941863117011", line 534, in write
    super(UnicodeDecodingStringIO, self).write(s)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

This is after confirming nltk is installed with `sc.list_packages()`.

```
Package                    Version
-------------------------- -------
...
nltk                       3.4.5  
...
```

And importing nltk with `import nltk`.

This problem feels like it comes from my lack of understanding over how EMR is setup.

Is there anything I should try to debug this?

### **UPDATE:**

I've tried installing it in a bootstrap script, which properly installs.

```
pip install nltk
python -m nltk.downloader wordnet
```

But then I still get this error when trying to use it.

```
An error occurred while calling o166.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 7, ip-172-31-1-163.ca-central-1.compute.internal, executor 3): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 86, in __load
    root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, zip_name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 701, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource wordnet not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('wordnet')

  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load corpora/wordnet.zip/wordnet/

  Searched in:
    - '/home/nltk_data'
    - '/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576604798325_0001/container_1576604798325_0001_01_000005/virtualenv_application_1576604798325_0001_0/nltk_data'
    - '/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576604798325_0001/container_1576604798325_0001_01_000005/virtualenv_application_1576604798325_0001_0/share/nltk_data'
    - '/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576604798325_0001/container_1576604798325_0001_01_000005/virtualenv_application_1576604798325_0001_0/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576604798325_0001/container_1576604798325_0001_01_000005/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576604798325_0001/container_1576604798325_0001_01_000005/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576604798325_0001/container_1576604798325_0001_01_000005/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 345, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576604798325_0001/container_1576604798325_0001_01_000005/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 141, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576604798325_0001/container_1576604798325_0001_01_000005/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 334, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576604798325_0001/container_1576604798325_0001_01_000005/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576604798325_0001/container_1576604798325_0001_01_000005/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 19, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 19, in <listcomp>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/stem/wordnet.py", line 41, in lemmatize
    lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 123, in __getattr__
    self.__load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 88, in __load
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 83, in __load
    root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, self.__name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 701, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError:
```

### **UPDATE**

I found the directory that `wordnet` is being downloaded to by the shell script, and confirmed its actually there by ssh'ing into the server.

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package wordnet to /root/nltk_data...
```

So in jupyter I'm checking `nltk.data.path`

```
['/var/lib/livy/nltk_data', '/tmp/1576616653412-0/nltk_data', '/tmp/1576616653412-0/share/nltk_data', '/tmp/1576616653412-0/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/local/share/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data']
```

And appending my new path.

```
nltk.data.path.append('/root/nltk_data')
nltk.data.path
```

We can see it added.

```
['/var/lib/livy/nltk_data', '/tmp/1576616653412-0/nltk_data', '/tmp/1576616653412-0/share/nltk_data', '/tmp/1576616653412-0/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/share/nltk_data', '/usr/local/share/nltk_data', '/usr/lib/nltk_data', '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data', '/root/nltk_data']
```

But it's still not being searched in when I try to call a function that uses that corpora.

```
  Resource wordnet not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('wordnet')

  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load corpora/wordnet.zip/wordnet/

  Searched in:
    - '/home/nltk_data'
    - '/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576615748346_0001/container_1576615748346_0001_01_000006/virtualenv_application_1576615748346_0001_0/nltk_data'
    - '/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576615748346_0001/container_1576615748346_0001_01_000006/virtualenv_application_1576615748346_0001_0/share/nltk_data'
    - '/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1576615748346_0001/container_1576615748346_0001_01_000006/virtualenv_application_1576615748346_0001_0/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
```

No reference to `/root/nltk_data` here

Comment: The problem you seem to run into is not where the data *is* on the driver, but that this data *does not exist at that location* on the worker nodes. The answer below probably works (using the bootstrap action), I do not know (yet) if you can also achieve this after the cluster has already been started.

Answer (score 4):

Given the inability to change the path used to load `wordnet` (changing `nltk.data.path` wasn't changing where nltk looked for the files).

I had to change the directory it was being downloaded into from the boot script to match where nltk looks by default.

**Boot script**

```
sudo pip install nltk
sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /home/nltk_data wordnet
```

Comment: it works. In my bootstrap action script I added this and then start EMR.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me on EMR using the bootstrap action

```
mkdir /home/hadoop/nltk_data
python3.6 -m nltk.downloader -d /home/hadoop/nltk_data stopwords
```

The `python3.6` might change based on the EMR release.

Also, the below one works for both pyspark and livy

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/nltk_data
sudo python3.6 -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/lib/nltk_data stopwords
```